# Why C function for stream start with character f?

Tags: c, printf, scanf

Good day! Just curious why C function for stream start with f?
Is there are any historical reason?
Or like the name, it require a FILE handle for all of those functions (It hook up a file space for OS)?
By understand this I will have more solid understanding about C.

Such as:

```
printf(), fprintf()

vprintf(), vfprintf()

puts(), fputs()

scanf(), fscanf()

gets(), fgets()
```

Comment: That's more of a 'google foo' question than a stack overflow question. Someone here might know, but your best bet is searching for the web.

Comment: Initial `f` in function names is for `FILE`. The trailing `f` in functions is for "format".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question.

Comment: I think for you it's a silly question. but for me it's important and I am new to C. That is the way I found programming interesting by understand the naming convention. I think all professional programming is follow a naming conversion and that provide a good foundation for them to build a solid system.PS. I tried search Google but none match this, that's why I ask that question.

Answer (score 2):

The **f**  in the function start  stands for **file**

Comment: Umm OK, how is that new or different from the comment by dash?

Comment: it was written almost at at the same time while i was typing the answer.

Comment: Prad answered the question, dash answered it with a comment.  You can't mark a a comment as correct.

Comment: i can delete the answer and if you guys want and think i am taking credit